# HTTP request fails with timeout android

Tags: android, http

i am learning connect server with http client, but  when i am request data, usualy fail and timeout, how to fix it ?

this my code

```
public void detailURL(String url) {
            Log.v("Android Spinner JSON Data Activity", url);
            mTask=new Detail().execute(url); 
}

private class Detail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private static final int REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT = 3 * 1000;
    private static final int WAIT_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000;
    private final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();
HttpResponse response;
    private String content = null;
    private boolean error = false;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ProfileActivity.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Getting your data... Please wait...");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String URL = null;
        try {
    URL = urls[0];
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data,file_name);  
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
        //add name value pair for the country code
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("foto", bab);                     
        reqEntity.addPart("tag", new StringBody(register_tag));
        reqEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody(name));
        reqEntity.addPart("email", new StringBody(email));
        reqEntity.addPart("namalengkap", new StringBody(namalengkap));
        reqEntity.addPart("telepon", new StringBody(telepon));
        reqEntity.addPart("val_lokasi_alamat", new StringBody(val_lokasi_alamat));
        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            content = out.toString();
        } else{
        //Closes the connection.
        Log.w("HTTP1:",statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
    }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.w("HTTP2:",e );
        content = e.getMessage();
        error = true;
        cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("HTTP3:",e );
        content = e.getMessage();
        error = true;
        cancel(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("HTTP4:",e );
        content = e.getMessage();
        error = true;
        cancel(true);
        }                       
    return content;
}

protected void onCancelled() {
    mTask.cancel(true);
    btn_enable();
    ProgressLoadStartRegister.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    statusKoneksi();
}

protected void onPostExecute(String content) {

    if (error) {
        mTask.cancel(true);
        ProgressLoadStartRegister.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn_enable();
        statusKoneksi();
        // getUpdate();
    } else {
        ProgressLoadStartRegister.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        displaystatis_kontenDetail(content);
        mTask.cancel(true);
        btn_enable();
    }

}

}

private void displaystatis_kontenDetail(String response){

        JSONObject json = null; 

        try {
                json = new JSONObject(response); 
                Log.d("json", json.toString());
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                         GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(getApplicationContext(), true);
                        // user successfully registred
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        Intent LoginActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        LoginActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(LoginActivity);
                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Silakan cek kotak masuk atau spam email anda untuk konfirmasi keaktifan akun",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        // Error in registration
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username atau Email sudah terdaftar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

 private void statusKoneksi(){

            statusKoneksiRegister.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            statusKoneksiRegister.startAnimation(animstatuskoneksi);
            handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                       statusKoneksiRegister.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       statusKoneksiRegister.clearAnimation();
                }
            }, 4500);
            }
```

usualy **error = true;**

```
protected void onPostExecute(String content) {

            if (error) {
                mTask.cancel(true);
                ProgressLoadStartRegister.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_enable();
                statusKoneksi();

                //getUpdate();
            } else {
                ProgressLoadStartRegister.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                displaystatis_kontenDetail(content);
                mTask.cancel(true);
                btn_enable();
            }

            }
```

this permession in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.droidersuin.project.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.droidersuin.project.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

     <permission
        android:name="com.droidersuin.project.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="com.droidersuin.project.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

sorry with my english, thanks your participant ... :)

Comment: try to comment this lines then test   .. HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
                        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);
                        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);

Comment: Check for internet permission in the Android Manifest file

Comment: niteshgoel : i will try :) thanks
DineshPrajapati : i have set permission internet :)

Comment: problem might be occurring because of timeout values which you have set. can you please post your error logs here ?

Comment: post your manifest file and make sure you have internet permission

Comment: greedy : after i try comment lines like nitesh goel, not yet log ,..
shylendra : i edited post